# Not getting auth headers when setting axios default

Tags: node.js, axios

I am trying to send an auth header along with an axios POST request from inside a Vue application. I currently am getting a 401 from my back end with an auth header that works when I do a curl.

I've tried splitting it up into variables and putting it in but that did not work and resulted in the same error (401).

This is just the axios code I am trying to get to work. I have checked with console.log and all values I am trying to send exist, though I don't know how to check the axios headers before sending.

```
axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = JWTtoken;
axios.post(updateURL, {
  token: result.token
});
```

The backend code can't be changed easily for testing so need to figure out why not sending from the front end

I'd like it to send the correct header along with my request so I don't get a 401 status code.

Comment: You need to debug the problem from the network tab using Chrome and selecting the endpoint the `axios.post()` is calling. You are able to see the headers from there.

Comment: Are you sure that Header it's "Authorization"? Isn't "x-access-token" or something?
Did you tried to send manually?

Comment: Based on the code snippet on `axios`, I cannot tell if there is anything wrong.

Comment: @GabrielLopes 100% sure as I was the dev for the backend and I can also make it work in postman with the header I said. No chance of it being something else unless express/passport accepts multiple different ones.

Comment: The axios code is correct (https://jsfiddle.net/biutas/qL6y149g/), if in postman it works, try to compare what it's diffrent on header.

Comment: Hm.. as far as I remember you have to add "Bearer [Your JWT Tokens here]" inside "Authorization" header. Do take a look at their docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this..

```
axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + JWTtoken;
axios.post(updateURL, {
  token: result.token
});
```

Notice that I add `Bearer` in the `Authorization`. It is how JWT was meant to be used according to their [introduction](https://jwt.io/introduction/).

However, if the answer is wrong. Help us by providing more information about your `response` in Developer Console as  @RuChernChong suggest. Any error logs would be helpful as well.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up figuring it out before seeing your comment but yes this was the issue. Marked you as correct so others see, TY

Answer (score 0):

Another way by using [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) globals to set for example `X-Auth-Token` encoding from [JWT.io](https://jwt.io/) directly like this:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common["X-Auth-Token"] = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c";
```

Comment: That would not work when the application is looking for the authorization header.